# What are the steps to solving |3x + 1| > |2x - 7| with the given answer as $(-∞,-8)\cup(6/5,∞)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

What are the steps to solving $|3x + 1| > |2x - 7|$ with the given answer as $(-∞,-8)\cup(6/5,∞)$?

I am having difficulty with understanding inequalities with absolute value functions on both sides, what are the steps for solving this example problem?

Comment: I suppose you could learn from some similar question that have been posted on this site, for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460066/inequalities-absolute-value-2x-1-leq-x-3, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26564/solving-inequality-with-two-absolute-values or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158906/the-solution-set-of-left-frac2x-32x-3-right-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to lab's response, a useful trick is to draw a picture of the real line. On it, indicate the critical points at which your absolute value functions switch signs. (In this case, those points are $-\frac{1}{3}$ and $3.5$.) Now, consider the various cases where $x$ may be located on that real line.

For example, for $x\geq 3.5$ (i.e. $x$ lies on or to the right of the point $3.5$), then $|3x+1|=3x+1$ and $|2x-7|=2x-7$ so you have
$$
3x+1>2x-7\implies x>-8
$$
which is already satisfied for all $x\geq 3.5$. So $x\geq 3.5$ works. Now you move on to the next case (e.g. $-\frac{1}{3}\leq x<3.5$).

---

EDIT: fine, a bit more details: now that we have established $x\geq 3.5$ works, consider $-\frac{1}{3}\leq x<3.5$. In this case, $|3x+1|=3x+1$ and $|2x-7|=7-2x$ so
$$
3x+1>7-2x\implies 5x>6\implies x>\frac{6}{5}.
$$
So if $-\frac{1}{3}\leq x<3.5$, you want $x>\frac{6}{5}$. In other words, $x\in(\frac{6}{5},3.5)$ works.

Finally, consider $x<-\frac{1}{3}$. Then, $|3x+1|=-3x-1$ and $|2x-7|=7-2x$ so
$$
-3x-1>7-2x\implies x<-8.
$$
So you want $x\in(-\infty,-\frac{1}{3})\cap(-\infty,-8)=(-\infty,-8)$.

Putting all cases together, the solution set is
$$
(-\infty,-8)\cup(\frac{6}{5},3.5)\cup[3.5,\infty)=(-\infty,-8)\cup(\frac{6}{5},\infty).
$$
All this is a lot easier if you have a picture while following it.

---

EDIT 2: another visual aid for simple cases like this is to plot both the left hand side and right hand side. This is another way to make sure you understand how the absolute value function works. You should get something like this:

[image]

Now, you are interested in the values of $x$ where the red line is **above** the blue line.

Comment: I have x > -8 as one case, and x < 6/5 as the other, yet the answer confuses me, shouldn't it be (-8,6/5)?

Comment: More or less, step by step is what I need to understand.

Comment: Would it help if I said I have solved this analytically? Those are the steps I am needing.

Comment: Just compare the steps you have with those I have written above and see the differences.

Comment: The graph was a great help! Now I understand the relation to the answer and how it is written for absolute value inequalities. Thank you Kim.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Don't forget to upvote answers like lab's and mine if they have helped you. It's a small appreciative gesture that helps keep the community going.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As for real $x, |x|=+x$ if $x\ge0$ and $-x,$ if $x<0$

Check for  $3x+1<=>0$ and $2x-7<=>0$

Comment: What I was shown in class was a little confusing, the next step I took was 3x + 1 > 2x - 7  or  3x + 1 < -(2x - 7)... this is where I get stuck, I have the right numerical values in my answers, but just backwards, is there a shift in inequality signs in the arithmetic?

Comment: @Thetasquared, What's your confusion?

Comment: The answer (-∞,-8)U(6/5,∞) confuses me, doesn't that mean that all answers from negative ∞ until negative 8 are acceptable plus all numbers from 6/5 to ∞ are accepted? But with the answers I worked out I have x > -8 and x < 6/5 which is all numbers in between -8 and 6/5 are acceptable. These are two different answers.

Comment: Would it help if I said I have solved this analytically? Those are the steps I am needing.

Comment: @Thetasquared, Please let me know if the other answer is not sufficient

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could also use the fact that $|a|^2=a^2$.

The original inequality
$$|3x+1|>|2x-7|$$
is equivalent to
$$(3x+1)^2>(2x-7)^2.$$
(Since both sides are positive, squaring gives an equivalent inequality. This would not be true for arbitrary inequality.)

Now with some manipulation you should be able to get
$$5x^2+34x-48=5(x^2+\frac{34}5x-\frac{48}5)>0$$
and then solve this quadratic inequality.

The same approach was used in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/460144/) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/460076/) to a similar question.