# Solve $|2x−3| < |x+5|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I've tried solving $$|2x-3|=|x+5|$$ but the same method does not look applicable here.

$$2x-3 = x+5, \text{if}\; x>3/2$$

$$2x-3= -(x+5), \text{if} \; x<3/2$$

This method was not working here.

Comment: What is the "same method"? Same as what?

Comment: What are the values of $ \vert 2x-3 \vert, \vert x+5\vert$ for $x \in (-\infty,-5), (-5, 3/2), (3/2, \infty)$? Can you solve the inequalities on each of those intervals? And finally, get a conclusion?

Comment: When solving the equality, you do not need to care wether $x>\frac 32 $ or not...$$|a|=|b| \Leftrightarrow a=b \vee a=-b$$

Comment: basically i'm looking for how to deal with |a| > |b| form. I'm used to solving problems in the form |a| = |b|.

Comment: @Fr0zenF0x But your problem **is** in the form $|a|=|b|$...

Comment: @5xum check the title ;).

Comment: For this particular example, you could also draw the two functions as it is quite easy to do so. Of course, this could become hard for other functions

Comment: You could check some other posts with similar topic, such as: [Inequalities with two absolute values with greater than symbol. Please tell me the proper way of doing $|4x-1|>|3x+2|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3436407), [The solution set of $\left | \frac{2x - 3}{2x + 3} \right |< 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/158906), 
[Inequalities - Absolute Value $|2x-1| \leq |x-3|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/460066),
[What are the steps to solving |3x + 1| > |2x - 7| with the given answer as $(-∞,-8)\cup(6/5,∞)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/916678), etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have\begin{align}|2x-3|<|x+5|&\iff|2x-3|^2<|x+5|^2\\&\iff3x^2-22x-16<0\\&\iff3\left(x+\frac23\right)(x-8)<0\\&\iff x\in\left(-\frac23,8\right).\end{align}

Comment: This is simple and brilliant!

Answer (score 3):

I'll just leave a less conventional approach for discussion. Once you solve $|2x-3| =|x+5|$, leading to $x=-\frac 23 \vee x = 8$, by continuity, you know that on each interval
$$
(-\infty,-\frac23), \quad (-\frac 23, 8), \quad (8,+\infty)
$$

Either the ">" or "<" inequalities are satisfied. To determine which holds on each interval, just probe it with specific points. For instance, using $x = -1, 0, 9$, you conclude that

- $|2(-1)-3| > |-1+5| \Rightarrow |2x-3|>|x+5| $ on $(-\infty, -\frac 23)$
- $|2(0)-3| < |0+5| \Rightarrow |2x-3|< |x+5|$ on $(-\frac 23, 8)$
- $|2(9)-3| > |9+5| \Rightarrow |2x-3| > |x+5|$ on $(8,+\infty)$.

Comment: Ye I love this approach, actually one of my friends suggested me this ;) But I'm actually looking for a more formal method, If that makes sense.

Comment: This is not less formal then other methods, but it does require continuity of the expressions. For a totally automatic approach, you can just cover every sign possibility of both expressions inside modules and solve the in equalities (without modules) that you obtain in each case.

Answer (score 1):

There are two nodes $x=3/2$ and $x=-5$, so we have to consider the in-equation $|2x-3|< |x+5|$ in three regions three regions

I: $x\le -5 \implies 3-2x<-(x+5) \implies x>8$ (A contradiction).

II:$-5 <x\le 3/2 \implies 3-2x<x+5 \implies x>-2/3 \implies -2/3<x\le 3/2$

III: $x>3/2 \implies 2x-3 <x+5 \implies x<8 \implies 3/2<x \le 8$

Finally, by combining I and II we get the total solution as $x\in (-2/3,8].$

Comment: $x=8$ does not satisfy the inequality...

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake, corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$|a|=a,\text{if } a\ge0$$
and
$$|a|=-a, \text{if } a\le0$$
Similar holds for $b$.

So to solve
$$|a|<|b$$
you have four cases

case 1:
$$a<b, a\ge0, b\ge 0$$
case 2:
$$-a<b, a\le0, b\ge 0$$
case 3:
$$a<-b, a\ge0, b\le0$$
case 4:
$$-a<-b,a\le0,b\le0$$

So can you solve it noe?